# Random guessing game java, i cant get the play again function to work

Tags: java

This is my code below, i need to insert a play again function and a method that allows me to save the user name, number of attempts, number of successful attempts and the players best score to a text file! I have to repeat this bit of coursework to get back into my second year of university so any pointers about the code in generally would be greatly appreciated. I was never that good at programming so i'm badly stuck. This is my first time posting on this site as well due to recommendations of a friend so thanks in advance

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GuessingGame3 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Random generator = new Random(); //This is were the computer selects the Target

        int guess;
        int count = 0;
        int Target;
        String userName;
        int answer;
        boolean play = true; 
        int attempt = 6;

        Scanner consoleIn = new Scanner(System.in); 
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.println("Hello! Please enter your name:\n"); //This is were the user enters his/her name
        userName= name.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Hello "+ userName + " :) Welcome to the game!\n");

        while (play == true)
        {
            Target = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
            System.out.println("Can you guess the number i'm thinking off? You will have "+ attempt +" attempts to guess the correct number"); //This is where the computer asks the user to guess the number and how many guesses they will have

            do {
                guess = consoleIn.nextInt();
                count++;
                attempt -= 1;

                if (guess > Target)
                System.out.println("Sorry! Your guess was too high! You have "+ attempt +" attempts left!"); //This is to help the player get to the answer 
                else 
                if (guess < Target)
                System.out.println("Sorry! Your guess was too low! You have "+ attempt +" attempts left!"); //This is to help the player get to the answer 
               }        
                while(guess != Target && count <6);

                if(guess == Target) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations "+  userName + ", it took you "+ count +" attempts to guess correctly!"); //This tells the player that they got the correct answer and how many attempts it took
                    }

                else 
                {
                System.out.println("Sorry "+ userName + ", You've used up all of your guesses! The correct answer was "+ Target + "!");  //This tells the player that they failed to find the number and then tells them what the correct answer  
                }
                {
                while(guess = Target || count > 6);
                System.out.println("Would you like to play again "+ userName +"? [Y?N]:\n");
                Answer = answer.nextLine();
                if (Answer = "Y")
                    play = true;
                    else
                        if (Answer = "N")
                            System.out.println("Thanks for playing "+ userName +" :)! Please come back soon!");
                            }
                            break;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us what you have

Comment: Until you show some code of what yuou have we can't answer precisely. In general, you either need to write to some persistent location (such as a file) your information if you want to have it survive applications restarts, otherwise if you just want to save it for the lifetime of the application you can store it in memory in some appropriate data container.

Comment: Thats the code up now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the user above noted, you need this to be Answer == Y. YOu should not use strings, but characters. You should also use 'ToUpperCase()' to ensure that it will still work if the user inputs 'y' I recommend using .nextChar() instead of nextLine(), in case the user accidentily inputs a string with more than one character. for example if they bump the t button while pressing y.

Comment: or `Answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")` but then again, op never actually declared answer.. So .. yaknow..

Comment: When i use "Answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y") its points to the "." and says can't find the symbol

Comment: I suggested the toUpperCase since I think strings should not be used in this instance.  I maintain this recommendation.